# accessing subfolder of cakephp site

Tags: cakephp, subdirectory

I have develop a site using cakephp and upload to www.example.com. Now I want to have some html pages in subfolder like www.example.com/subsite.

Please help how I can do this as cakephp take subsite as controller name and redirect it to main site. how I can display the html pages under subsite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can be done by placing the html pages in the app/webroot folder

```
http://www.example.com/subsite
```

would be

```
app/webroot/subsite/index.html
```

as an example.  If you are talking about actual pages in your cakephp then you could do that by creating a controller.

Comment: It worked but please can you help if a subsite is same cakephp application then how we can access it from subfolder. When I copy the cakephp application in app/webroot then it access it by app/webroot/subsite. I want to access it by example.com/subsite not example.com\app\webroot\subsite. Sorry I did not include this point in my question.

Comment: its a bit old but u may get the idea..try this link...http://www.virtualapplicationserver.com/CakePHP_MultipleInstallNotes.html

Comment: the easiest thing to do would be to write something in your mod_rewrite in .htaccess that would be similar to this:

`RewriteRule    ^subsite/([^/.]+)/?$ webroot/subsite/$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading up on how your routes.php file works.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

Also, I saw a tutorial somewhere, where someone edited their error files to act as a makeshift router. The tutorial was quite old, but the idea is still there.
Basically, when the error page would normally show page not found, it would check a folder to see if the requested controller was actually a file. If found, display that file, otherwise, give the standard page not found error.
You could try something of the similar.

Answer (score 0):

Set it up as a plugin by putting it in your `/app/plugins` folder, ie: `/app/plugins/subsite`. You can then access it at  www.example.com/subsite